# Convergence in norm and equivalence

Tags: functional-analysis

For a fixed positive integer n, the spaces l(n,p) consist of a single underlying linear space defined on it. Show that all the norms are equivalent.

I have shown that convergence in l(n,p) amounts to coordinatewise convergence. How do I prove the equivalence of norms?

Comment: Huh? What is $l(n,p)$???

Comment: I guess it's $\Bbb R^n$ with the $p$-norm.

Comment: Yes, it is. I am sorry I could not format that way.

Answer (score 1):

*sketch of proof:*
Let $x$ in $\mathbb R^n$ and $1\leq p <\infty$.
Then one can show
$$
|x_i| \leq \| x \|_p
$$
for all coordinates $i$.
It follows that
$$
\|x\|_\infty \leq \| x \|_p.
$$

On the other hand, one can show
$$
\| x \|_p \leq n \max_{i=1 \dots n} | x_i |.
$$

Thus we have shown that $\|\cdot\|_p$ and $\|\cdot\|_\infty$
are equivalent.
It follows that all $\ell(n,p)$-norms are equivalent.